# Azure AppService multiple instances no parallel handling

Tags: azure

I wanted to benchmark cloud services so I wanted to run this [php benchmark](http://www.php-benchmark-script.com/) on azure App service. When i have 1 core 1 instance app service plan, the incoming requests are handled one by one (no parallel handling). When I switch to 2 core plan, the requests are handled parallel to each other. BUT when I use 1 core plan and 2 instances, it doesn't handle the requests in parallel. So what do instances exactly do, when the app runs only on one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was caused by two things:

1. there is ARR affinity , which makes consecutive requests go to the same instance, [here is tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/) how to disable it.
2. I didn't know about [Google's 6](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12066), so my requests were stalled locally